# get most current record if*

Tags: sql, database

i have a set of data for service jobs and i want to identify customers that still have an old part installed (part x) but if that customer has the new replacement part (part y) then i dont want them to populate in my data. The best way i can describe it is think of a recall. Now every Job has a number, that number is always increasing with new jobs across the customer. So im looking for where (part x) has been installed (part y) has not. Customers all have a customer number that any jobs are associated to. In my example below Customers (12373,12369,12349) would all show up on my list but customer (12365,would not because they were upgraded to part y on a numerically higher job #.

[image: example table]

Any help would be great, new to sql

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (The answer will probably depend on which product it is.)

Comment: Also add the expected result!

Comment: Is 'part w' a new replacement part too? Do you want all the customers with jobs that have 'part x', but not a higher part letter?

Comment: `row_number() over (partition by customer_number) where row_number = 1 and parts = 'part x'` if supported, generate two data contains customer and job iwth with X parts one with customer and job with y parts.  LEFT Join the two where customers match and job Number on X part is >= job on y part or is null.

Answer (score 1):

My version :)

```
SELECT
    t1.* 
FROM
    `table` AS t1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            `Customer Number` 
        FROM
            `table`
        WHERE
            `Parts` > 'part x'
    ) AS t2
        ON ( t1.`Customer Number` = t2.`Customer Number` )
WHERE
    t1.`Parts` = 'part x'
    AND t2.`Customer Number` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

General sql syntax. Can be a bit shorter in some modern DBMSes, but perfomance should be good enough when index on (customerNumber, jobNumber) exists.

```
select customerNumber, jobNumber, parts
from theTable t1
where parts='part x' and not exists (
    select 1 
    from theTable t2 
    where t2.customerNumber = t1.customerNumber 
          and t2.jobNumber > t1.jobNumber
          and t2.parts='part y')
```